# Angular Reactive Forms: Dynamic Select dropdown value not binding

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have two arrays of data: AssociatedPrincipals (previously saved data) and ReferencePrincipals (static data to populate in dropdown controls).  I'm struggling to get the previous value from AssociatedPrincipals to be displayed/selected in a *dynamic amount* (most examples use a single dropdown) of dropdowns on page load.

I'm not certain how to set up the form (code behind and HTML), especially setting the Select's formControlName.  Currently, the static values in each dropdown populate, but I cannot get the *selected value* to bind properly.

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.factsForm = this.formbuilder.group({
        associatedPrincipals: this.formbuilder.array([]),
        referencePrincipals: this.formbuilder.array([])
    });

    // Data for both of these methods comes from external source...
    var responseData = // HTTP source...
    // Push retrieved data into form
    this.initPrincipals(responseData[0]);
    // Push static data into form
   this.initStaticData(responseData[1]);
}

public initPrincipals(principals?: IAssociatedPrincipal[]): FormArray {
    principals.forEach((principal) => {
 this.associatedPrincipals.push(this.createPrincipalFormGroup(principal));
    });
}

public initStaticData(response: IReferencePrincipal[]) {
   response.forEach((principal) => {
      this.referencePrincipals.push(
           this.formbuilder.control({
                code: principal.code,
                canHaveLead: principal.canHaveLead,
                isDuplicate: false
              }));
        });
}

public createPrincipalFormGroup(principal: IAssociatedPrincipal) {
        return this.formbuilder.group({
            code: principal.code,
            canHaveLead: false,
            isDuplicate: false
        });
    }

public get associatedPrincipals(): FormArray {
        return this.factsForm.get('associatedPrincipals') as FormArray;
    }

    public get referencePrincipals(): FormArray {
        return this.factsForm.get("referencePrincipals") as FormArray;
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <form novalidate [formGroup]="factsForm">
        <div formArrayName="associatedPrincipals">
             <div *ngFor="let associatedPrincipal of associatedPrincipals.controls; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i" >
                <select class="form-control create-input"
                        formControlName="i">
                     <option value=null disabled selected hidden>--Select--</option>
                       <option *ngFor="let refPrincipal of referencePrincipals.controls" [ngValue]="refPrincipal">refPrincipal.value.code</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
         </div>
    </form>
```

I appreciate any feedback!

**EDIT: Added Plunker showing the issue:** https://embed.plnkr.co/XMLvFUbuc32EStLylDGO/

Comment: Can you create plunker to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Yea, I'm going to suggest the same thing. I think we really need to see a working version of your issue with a Plunker.

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks.  Please see hero-list.component HTML and TS.  Static data populates in dropdowns which is good, but previously selected Chicago and San Diego values should be set.  Instead, the placeholder is set.
 https://embed.plnkr.co/XMLvFUbuc32EStLylDGO/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Problems in your demo

Based on the demo you provided, There are several problems as listed below:

- There is no `formControlName` assigned to `select`.
- You are binding **object** to select's option.

### **For the first problem**

Since you are looping through `associatedPrincipals` to show dropdownlist dynamically. And `associatedPrincipals` which is a *formArray* which can consider as below:

```
associatedPrincipals = {
  "0": FormControl,
  "1": FormControl
}
```

So you can simply assign `i` which is defined at `*ngFor` expression to `formControlName`.

```
<select formControlName="{{i}}" style="margin-top: 10px">
   ...
</select>
```

### **For the second problem**

While binding **object** to `option`, Angular will compare default value and `option`'s value by **object instance** by default.

You can set same instance(get from value of `referencePrincipals`'s formControls) to formControl of `associatedPrincipals`(as @Fetra R.'s answer). But this is not the most convenient way since you have to take some logic to keep the same instance of an object.

Here I would give you another solution which is using `compareWith` directive designed specifically for your current situation, see **[docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection)**.

Using `compareWith` directive, you just need to implement a `compareFun` to tell angular how to consider two objects(with different instances) as the same.Here yo can include `comparing object instance` and `comparing object fields` at the same time.

```
<select formControlName="{{i}}" style="margin-top: 10px" [compareWith]="compareFun">
  <option value=null disabled selected hidden>--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let refPrincipal of referencePrincipals.controls"
     [ngValue]="refPrincipal.value">{{ refPrincipal.value.code }}</option>
</select>

// tell angular how to compare two objects
compareFn(item1, item2): boolean {
  return item1 && item2 ? item1.code === item2.code : item1 === item2;
}
```

Refer **[docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection)** and fixed **[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/yIuQfRh7puq75e9VYKqZ?p=preview)** to learn detail about it.

Comment: wow, fantastic, thanks! A bit cleaner since we avoid extra typescript code to set the control values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the exact same reference of the object which populate the select into the selected one to get the selected value.

Here you use a value of all `FormControl` in `referencePrincipals`  to populate your `selectbox`, so to get it selected use this object:

```
public createPrincipalFormControl(principal) {
    const selectedFormControl = this.referencePrincipals.controls.find(form => form.value.code === principal.code)
    return this.formbuilder.control(selectedFormControl.value);
}
```

Working plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/vw3WZ6?p=preview

Comment: @dotNetkow Not willing to steal reputation from **Fetra R.**, just wanna provide a more convenient solution.

Comment: @Pengyy for sure, your solution with compareWith is more convenient. I even upvoted to thanks you for that. It's now open to dotNetKow to take a decision :)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 problems with your approach.

1. Your data source here is probably async. Which means you should not do `this.initiPrincipals(responseData[0])` immediately after `var responseData` but instead in callback of whatever method gets you the data or in a subscription to http service, if you get data through Observable.

   `let subscription = myservice.getmedata.subscribe(data =>
   {
   //here you should do your initializations with data from server
   };`

   If your data comes from @Input() then the right plase is `ngOnChanges`.
2. As Fetra pointed out, regardless of the fact that your previously selected option has exactly the same value as the ones you've prepopulated into select list, in order to set it as selected you need exact reference to the ones you've populated it with. so, something like:

   `this.formGroup.controls['yourSelectControl'].patchValue(this.yourInitialCollectionOfOptions.find(v => v.propertyByWhichYouWantToCompare == valueFromServer.propertyByWhichYouWantToCompare)`