# Angular Select default value shows empty

Tags: angular, select

I am developing Angular 4 Application, which have a dropdown with a default value populated. But my below code is not working for `default` selection. It shows blank regardless of what I set via `ngModel`.

```
<div class="form-group form-ctrl-display header-button-align">
  <select name="selectDepartment" class="form-control form-control-sm"
    [class.faded]="format.isEmpty(filter.Department)"
    style="max-width: 94px"
    [(ngModel)]="filter.Department"
    placeholder="Department">

    <option *ngFor="let department of filterViewData.Departments"
      [ngValue]="department">
      {{department.Name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  {{filter.Department| json}}
</div>
```

I have double checked the json data and it looks Ok. Here is the screenshot

[image]

Already tried [Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value/41180705) but nothing works. Not sure what is the problem and whole day I cant figure out the reason.

Below is the json data:

**filter. Department**

```
{"DepartmentId":401,"Name":"Transport","IsActive":true}
```

**fiterViewData. Departments**

```
[{"DepartmentId":400,"Name":"IT","IsActive":true},   
{"DepartmentId":401,"Name":"Transport","IsActive":true},
{"DepartmentId":402,"Name":"Admin","IsActive":true}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Reactive Forms: Dynamic Select dropdown value not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164708/angular-reactive-forms-dynamic-select-dropdown-value-not-binding)

Comment: @Pengyy its not a reactive form and not adding any dynamic controls. All static with the data populated on server. I am not constructing form in component.ts. I tried with compareWith option, this also doesnt work

Comment: can you post your current data of `fiterViewData. Departments ` and `filter. Department`? So we can see what's the difference.

Comment: @Pengyy I have updated JSON data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While binding object to options of select, `compareWith` will make it simple to match `ngModel` value with option's value even when they **keep different instances**(the reason to your current problem).

template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="filter.Department" [compareWith]="compareFun">
  <option *ngFor="let department of filterViewData.Departments"
    [ngValue]="department">
    {{department.Name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

component:

```
compareFun(item1, item2) {
  // you can determine the rule of matching different objects(for example: DepartmentId)
  return item1 && item2 ? item1.DepartmentId === item2.DepartmentId : item1 === item2;
}
```

refer **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-comparewith?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**.

Comment: You nailed it.. It was a typo i copied the code which has `compareFn` but I ignored to see.. Thanks